# Can I stop Google Firebase Authentication Sign In with Twitter from opening a Twitter window?

Tags: twitter, firebase-authentication

I just added Google Authentication for sign-ins, and one of the options is sign in with Twitter. This is working, but Twitter doesn't just sign the user in and close the sign-in popup like Google does.

Instead, if the user has a bare bones Twitter account, it asks a series of questions like their interests, and then even opens a separate popup to Twitter just to make the user visit their site.

Is there any way to stop this spammy behavior? (This is a React + JS/Express project.)